# How can I make sure a BS4 request is being made with a socket on a list?

Tags: python, proxy, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a list of proxies like this one I would like to use in scraping with python:

```
proxies_ls = [  '149.56.89.166:3128',
            '194.44.176.116:8080',
            '14.203.99.67:8080',
            '185.87.65.204:63909',
            '103.206.161.234:63909',
            '110.78.177.100:65103']
```

and made a function in order to scrap a url using bs4 and requests module called crawlSite(url). Here's the code:

```
# Bibliotecas para crawl e regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import re

#Biblioteca para data
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime

#Biblioteca para escrita dos logs
import os
import errno

#Biblioteca para delay aleatorio
import time
import random

print('BOT iniciado: '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

proxies_ls = [  '149.56.89.166:3128',
            '194.44.176.116:8080',
            '14.203.99.67:8080',
            '185.87.65.204:63909',
            '103.206.161.234:63909',
            '110.78.177.100:65103']

def crawlSite(url):
    #Chrome emulation
    ua=UserAgent()
    header={'user-agent':ua.chrome}
    random.shuffle(proxies_ls)

    #Random delay
    print('antes do delay: '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    tempoRandom=random.randint(1,5)
    time.sleep(tempoRandom)

    try:
        randProxy=random.choice(proxies_ls)
        # Getting the webpage, creating a Response object emulated with chrome with a 30sec timeout.
        response = requests.get(url,proxies = {'https':randProxy},headers=header,timeout=30)
        print(response)
        print('Resposta obtida: '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

        #Avoid HTTP request errors
        if response.status_code == 404:
            raise ConnectionError("HTTP Response [404] - The requested resource could not be found")
        elif response.status_code == 409:            
            raise ConnectionError("HTTP Response [409] - Possible Cloudflare DNS resolution error")
        elif response.status_code == 403:
            raise ConnectionError("HTTP Response [403] - Permission denied error")
        elif response.status_code == 503:
            raise ConnectionError("HTTP Response [503] - Service unavailable error")
        print('RR Status {}'.format(response.status_code))
        # Extracting the source code of the page.
        data = response.text

    except ConnectionError:
        try:
            proxies_ls.remove(randProxy)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        randProxy=random.choice(proxies_ls)

    return BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
```

What I would like to do is to make sure only the proxies on that list are being used in the conection. 
The random part

```
 randProxy=random.choice(proxies_ls)
```

is working ok but the checking part if the proxy is valid or not isn't. Mainly because I still get 200 as response with a "made up proxy".

If I reduce the list to this:

```
proxies_ls = ['149.56.89.166:3128']
```

with a proxy that doesn't work I still get 200 as response! (I tried using a proxychecker like https://pt.infobyip.com/proxychecker.php and it doesn't work...)

So my questions are (I'll enumerate so it is easier):
a) Why am I getting this 200 response and not a 4xx response?
b) How can I force the request to use the proxies as I want?

Thank you,

Eunito.

Comment: Read the docs carefully: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies. You need to specify the protocol in your proxy dict `requests.get(url, proxies={'https':'http://%s'%randProxy}   (...))`. Right now you are only passing an IP-address and port.

Comment: Hi @Kalkran You're right! but even with that correction using the only proxy I mentioned above (     proxies_ls = ['149.56.89.166:3128'] ) I still get 200...

Comment: Possibly because you are crawling a HTTP site and not a HTTPS site? You are only giving it a proxy to use for HTTPS-sites.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs carefully, you have to specify in the dictionary the following things:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

- What protocol to use the proxy for
- What protocol the proxy uses
- The address and port of the proxy

A "working" dict should look as follows:

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'
}
```

This will proxy ONLY and ALL **https** requests. This means it will NOT proxy **http**.

So to proxy all webtraffic, you should configure your dict like so:

```
proxies = {
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'
    'http':  'socks5://localhost:9050'
}
```

and substitute IP-addresses where necessary, of course. See  the following example for what happens otherwise:

```
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> proxies = {'https':'http://149.58.89.166:3128'}
>>> # Get a HTTP page (this goes around the proxy)
>>> response = requests.get("http://www.example.com/",proxies=proxies)
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> # Get a HTTPS page (so it goes through the proxy)
>>> response = requests.get("https://www.example.com/", proxies=proxies)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 485, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7d1f448c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)))
```

Comment: Fixed that part and added @chad suggestion! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

So basically, if I got your question right, you just want to check if the proxy is valid or not. `requests` has an exception handler for that, you can do something like this:

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError
try:
    response = requests.get(url,proxies = {'https':randProxy},headers=header,timeout=30)
except ProxyError:
    # message proxy is invalid
```